# respond_to not rendering index.js.erb properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've searched high and low for an answer to this and have yet to find anything that resolves my issues. I have a page that displays a message board from all users, and each message board has a "game_type" attribute tied to it. I'm simply trying to update all of the messages without refreshing using ajax. I've set up scopes, and my controller currently looks like this:

```
def index
    @microposts = Micropost.where(nil).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
    filtering_params(params).each do |key, value|
      @microposts = @microposts.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
    end
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build 

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { }
        format.js { }
    end

end
```

If I have just a standard link on my page such as `<%= link_to 'Mode', {controller: 'microposts', action: 'index', :game_type => 'Mode'} %>` my browser redirects to http://localhost:3000/microposts?game_type=Mode and displays the correct results. Now the issue occurs when trying to make the ajax magic happen so I can skip the redirect and render the results live on page.

Amongst other things, I have this form in my index.html.erb view:

```
<%= form_tag microposts_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <%= select_tag :game_type, options_for_select([['Mode', 'Mode'], ['Mode2', 'Mode2']]), onchange: 'this.form.submit()' %>
<% end %>
```

Which allows the user to filter the results through a select. I have an index.js.erb file that contains the following line:

```
$(.row.posts").html("<%= j (render @microposts) %>");`
```

However, when selecting a value from the drop down, my `format.js` block is not getting hit at all, and it's treating my request as HTML. The only way I've found to get around this is by adding `microposts_path(:format => :js)` to my form. This *kind of* works. First, I was getting a cross-origin error, which I resolved by adding `protect_from_forgery except: :index` to my controller. Now, my format.js block is hit and it's calling my index.js.erb. However, the JS calls in that file that I have are being rendered as text, and I am redirected to a blank page with just `$(.row.posts").html("the html of my rendered posts");`

Nothing in that file is actually treated as JS. I noticed in my browser console that I am getting this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript: "http://localhost:3000/microposts.js?utf8=%E2%9C%93&game_type=Mode".
```

The weird thing is, I have create and destroy actions that handle this just fine. My application.js file has both

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And I don't have any need to pass in `format: :js` with my other actions. Please help!! I may be way off base with the way I'm handling this from the get go, I cannot find anything that has been able to work for this!

Comment: Using Google Chrome, you can use the dev tools (F12) to inspect the different request sent by your client and the responses from your server. You can use this to inspect the request headers and see if at some point a request was made with the wrong format (ex: asked with format html but response contained only JS)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured it out, posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is a problem with `onchange: 'this.form.submit()'` being in my form that skips the `remote: :true` part. Hope this helps someone in the future!